# Android AsyncTask - Start Next Activit From onPostExecute - Bad Idea?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an activity which performs a bunch of SQLite inserts as its very last act before starting another activity which relies on the just-inserted data.

I have just moved all the db stuff into an AsyncTask...and, yep, you guessed it, the new activity is being called before the previous one's inserts have completed.

Now, I'm happy with the speed of my db operations, but, how do I make my app wait for the AsyncTask to finish before starting the next activity?

I was thinkig about starting it fromonPostExecute, but that feels wrong, although I don't know why it would be if it is.

Currently all I intend to do in pre/postExecute is show a default dialog...but, that's obviously also failing because the next activity is starting as soon as the asyncTask is started :)

No need for AsyncTask usage here, or is there just a simple way to say "woah, boy, wait a sec!"? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK to launch the other activity on `onPostExecute`... in fact, it sounds reasonable in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it still beneficial to me to use AsyncTask in this case, where the inserts really are the only thing going on, the only thing I'm waiting for? Is there potential for speed increase, just because I'm taking the work off the UI thread?

Comment: If that's the only thing you are doing: use AsyncTask if inserting the rows is taking a lot of time, otherwise you don't need to. The idea of taking the work off the UI thread is that you can execute things that take more than 2 seconds to complete, so the user don't feel your app is frozen.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Between this and making my SQLite stuff transactional, I've got a 9 second operation down to less than 1 second.  Pretty amazing, really.

Comment: "take more than 2 seconds to complete" -> you really should be thinking in terms of keeping stuff on the main thread to well below 1 second.  Otherwise the UI will feel unresponsive to the user.  100ms would be around the longest time, and well below 20ms to avoid glitching animations.